# Unicode in python with Django and MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm trying to compare two strings, the first one, s1, comes from mongoengine and the second one, s2, comes from a Django http request.

They look like this:

```
>>> s1 = product_model.Product.objects.get(pk=1).name
>>> s1
u'Product \xe4 asdf'
>>> s2 = request.POST['name']
>>> s2
'Product \xc3\xa4 asdf'
```

They have the same letter in them, the Swedish 'ä', but mongoengines (s1) is in a Python unicode string and Djangos (s2) is in a Python bytestring with unicode encoded characters.

I can easily solve this by e.g. converting the Python unicode string to be a byte string

```
>>> s1.encode('utf-8') == s2
True
```

But I would like to think that the best-practice is to have all my Python strings encoded the same way in my system, correct?

How can I tell Django to use Python unicode strings instead? Or how can I tell MongoEngine to use unicode encoded Python bytestrings?

Comment: I would not suggest to work with encoded strings. Like this slices say (http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) "Decode early, Unicode everywhere, encode late". So i would suggest you to tell Django to use unicode strings, but I am not Django expert, sorry. My approach: s1 == s2.decode("utf8"), so you have both Unicode strings to work with

Comment: Something appears to be wrong here, because in Django `request.POST['name']` should *always* give you a Unicode string. Django automatically decodes POST values to Unicode before it ever gets to your view.

Comment: Looks like @DanielRoseman is right: HttpRequest.POST -> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters, providing that the request contains form data. See the QueryDict documentation below. And QueryDict -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict works with Unicode strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/) docs says:

> General string handling
>
> Whenever you use strings with Django – e.g., in database lookups,
> template rendering or anywhere else – you have two choices for
> encoding those strings. You can use Unicode strings, or you can use
> normal strings (sometimes called “bytestrings”) that are encoded using
> UTF-8.
>
> In Python 3, the logic is reversed, that is normal strings are
> Unicode, and when you want to specifically create a bytestring, you
> have to prefix the string with a ‘b’. As we are doing in Django code
> from version 1.5, we recommend that you import unicode_literals from
> the **future** library in your code. Then, when you specifically want
> to create a bytestring literal, prefix the string with ‘b’.
>
> Python 2 legacy:
>
> ```
> my_string = "This is a bytestring"
> my_unicode = u"This is an Unicode string"
> ```
>
> Python 2 with unicode literals or Python 3:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>
> my_string = b"This is a bytestring"
> my_unicode = "This is an Unicode string"
> ```

If you are in Python 2, you can try that. As I said in the comment:

> I would not suggest to work with encoded strings. Like this slices say
> ([farmdev.com/talks/unicode](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)) **"Decode early, Unicode everywhere, encode
> late"**. So i would suggest you to tell Django to use unicode strings,
> but I am not Django expert, sorry. My approach: s1 ==
> s2.decode("utf8"), so you have both Unicode strings to work with

Hope it works

EDIT: I suppose you are using Django's HttpRequest, so from the docs:

> HttpRequest.encoding
>
> A string representing the current encoding used
> to decode form submission data (or None, which means the
> DEFAULT_CHARSET setting is used). You can write to this attribute to
> change the encoding used when accessing the form data. Any subsequent
> attribute accesses (such as reading from GET or POST) will use the new
> encoding value. Useful if you know the form data is not in the
> DEFAULT_CHARSET encoding.

Comment: Yea I tried to read this doc without really learning anything.. do you know where in Django I can set this in a general manner?
In settings.py so all Django strings is in the s2.decode('utf8') format as you say